# Pronunciation of ей vs ий

Tags: произношение

When both are unstressed and reduced, they would be **ɪj** and **ij** respectively. To me, however, they sound the same because the **ɪ** in combination with the **j** sound makes it sound the same is **ij**, especially when it is said quickly. Are they actually meant to sound distinguishably different, or is it purely orthographical?

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples where you cannot distinguish between "ей" and "ий"?

Comment: @Alex.S I didn't mean to say that it made it difficult to distinguish between words that sound similar, but was curious about how to pronounce ей.

Comment: I tried to "hear" differences between "ей" and "ий" and couldn't hear any (f.e. "с синей краской - синий дом", "в летней кухне - летний отпуск").

Comment: @Alex.S I thought it was just me, because I would try to say it out loud, emphasizing the ɪ as separate from the j sound, but it sounded very odd and not like real speech. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native I was able to hear the difference between `синий дом` - `с синей крышей` while saying it multiple times as carelessly as I could. It seems minor, but I can confirm that tongue is in different positions in these cases.

When you say `-ий` your tongue moves slightly closer to the top of a mouth, and when you say `-ей` tongue moves down a bit.

If I say `синей дом с синий крышей` in a normal voice to a person who doesn't know me, he will likely think that it's some sort of my dialect. My friends probably will notice it, but no one will say anything about it and many would not realize they have noticed it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suspected the lower tongue position. Seems subtle to me, I will have to practice the pronunciation a bit more! Thanks for the good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Never use IPA when speaking about Russian. It simply does not fit. Use phonetic analysis system taught in Russian schools.

The transcription of these words are

синей = [[с'ин'эй']](http://razborslova.ru/%D0%A1/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9)

синий = [[с'ин'ий']](http://razborslova.ru/%D0%A1/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

There are two different phonemes here. Even if they are not stressed they still retain their quality. Only [o]->[a] changes quality without stress.

Comment: I believe I have seen that reduced е is pronounced as something close to ɪ.

Comment: @Casey I do not know what IPA sign ɪ does mean, but unstressed е is not pronounced like и. Well, there can be variation but when it comes to phonemes, they are just as in the brackets above.

Comment: ɪ is similar to English i in bit. As I said, not exactly like ɪ, but close.

Comment: @Casey unstressed e is not pronounced as English i. It is pronounced as English e in "bet" but unstressed. If in doubt use the linked site for phonetic analysis.

Comment: @Casey again there can be variation and some people can pronounce it differently in fast speech but what should concern you is what phoneme is there fundamentally.

Comment: Yeah, I mostly pay attention to the "normal dialect," without shifts toward certain vowel changes.